# How to change boot order if I can't access legacy BIOS?

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, bootable-media, dell-vostro

I want to format an old notebook (Dell Vostro with windows 10) with a lightweight linux and it's just been a series of failures:

I tried making a bootable CD, but the CD drive apparently is not working. So I made a bootable USB.

So I tried booting with the USB, but it would boot straight to windows. So I set out to change the boot order.

The manufacturer logo screen says "press F2 for advanced boot, F12 for boot menu". Well, pressing F12 just doesn't work, and I can't confirm if it's the F12 key that is not working, or if it's a [common](https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/F12-Not-Working-to-Get-to-Boot-Menu/td-p/6243717) [problem](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Boot-Options-not-working-on-pressing-F12/td-p/4240338)

**EDIT: According to http://en.key-test.ru/, it is, indeed, the F12 key that is broken**

Pressing F2 works though, and takes me to the [Windows advanced boot options screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IXzH.png)

Ok then, I might be able to change the boot order through this screen, I thought. Numerous tutorials proposed going to the [UEFI firmware settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwrW5.png) on that very same menu, to change the boot order

I tried and... I don't have that option at all. I then learned that there are 2 types of BIOS: UEFI and Legacy, and mine is Legacy, which doesn't have that option.

So, I then set out to change my BIOS from Legacy to UEFI. I found out that there is a Microsoft [tool](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-convert-mbr-disk-gpt-move-bios-uefi-windows-10) that does just that, and that it comes with a certain update of windows 10.

So I tried updating windows through the Windows Update Assistant and an error occurs that stops the update from downloading.

**EDIT 2: I managed to make Windows Update assistant work. It downloaded the update and prompted to restart, like any normal update. Upon restarting, though, the computer just beeps non-stop and eventually boots to windows normally, without installing the updtes**

And that's a dead-end for me.

Any tips on how I can fix any of the steps above?

TL;DR: I just want to boot from an USB, but to do that I need to change the boot order, and to change the boot order I need to access the BIOS, and to access the BIOS I need to either press F12 on the manufacturer screen or access the UEFI setting, but the F12 key is broken and to have UEFI settings I need to have a UEFI type BIOS, and to have an UEFI type BIOS I need to change my partition type with the Microsoft tool above and to get the tool above I need to update Windows and Windows just won't update!

So, that's my chain of problems for something that should be incredibly simple. Any help? I'm absolutely at a dead-end

Comment: Hold the shift button down when you click shutdown in Windows 10, see if F12 works now.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. Check my edit: The F12 key is broken

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution: Plugged-in a keyboard with a working F12 key, and pressed it